# Does @SpringBootApplication scans test folder for configurations?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-autoconfiguration

I've a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in main class of my Spring Boot Application with ordinary folders structure (and `@SpringBootApplication` is one level package upper then beans in other packages)

I defined some `@Configuration` classes in some packages but under the `test` folder.

Will `@SpringBootApplication` autoconfigure it when start application?

Will `@SpringBootApplication` autoconfigure it when it will be finded by `@SpringBootTest` (it's also one level upper but in `test` folder) when test started?

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure, but I would say no, `@SpringBootApplication` does not scan `@Configuration` classes in your test folder. What you should use instead is `@TestConfiguration` and then in your `@SpringBootTest` add `@Import(YourTestConfiguration.class)`. Find an example below:

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class YourTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    (...)
}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Import(YourTestConfiguration.class)
class AppTests {
    (...)
}
```

You can read more about this and check complete examples in the following online resources:

- https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-testconfiguration/
- https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/springboot-test-configuration/

Comment: Yes, you are right: `@Import(YourTestConfiguration.class)` should be used, thank you anyway. But I unfortunately need the exact answer to my question

Comment: Well, the exact answer is that `@Configuration` classes are not scanned by `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: I see from my code it's scanned... let's see what others say and vote, I experimented, but possible the experiment is wrongly set..